# Showing the existence of a homeomorphism between two cofibres.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Suppose we have a pushout of pointed spaces, where $i$ and $j$ are cofibrations.

[image]

Let $M$ and $N$ be the cofibres of $i$ and $j$ respectively. Then show there is a homeomorphism $M\cong N$.

This question is quite short, and there are only a few definitions involved. I know the definitions of pushout, cofibre and cofibration, but I can't see how to show this. My guess is that I'm missing (or overlooking) some key result.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking for a *homeomorphism* in this case seems too strong, because to me the (homotopy) cofiber is only well defined up to homotopy.  There are point-set models of cofibers, e.g., the (reduced) mapping cone, but I wouldn't expect properties that aren't homotopy invariant to be preserved.

Concretely, let's assume that by cofiber you mean the reduced mapping cone construction.  Consider the pushout square
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
* & \xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}} & * \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
([0,1],0) & \xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}} & ([0,1],0).
\end{array}$$

The cofiber of the top row is again the point $M = *$, but the cofiber of the bottom row is homeomorphic to the 2-simplex, i.e., $N \cong \Delta^2$.  These spaces are obviously homotopy equivalent, but they are *not homeomorphic*: their cardinalities are different, so there isn't even a bijection between them.

Comment: Thank you very much, I found this very helpful!